# IE prevent changing selected radio button on group

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works well on Chrome to prevent the change of the selected radio button based on a field validation, but on IE it will uncheck all radio buttons.

Expected behavior: Just like in Chrome, it shouldn't let the user change the selected radio button by keeping the one that is checked, with the same checked status.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("[name=group1]").on("click", function(event){
   var dynamicValidation = false; //mock a field validation
    if (!dynamicValidation){
     return false;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="group1" value="1" checked="checked"> 
<label for="radio1">Option1</label>

<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="group1" value="2">
<label for="radio2">Option2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to have checked already on radios but this is a way to go about it.  This should work both in IE and Chrome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dynamicValidation = false; //mock a field validation
  if (!dynamicValidation) {
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="group1" value="1" checked="checked">
<label for="radio1">Option1</label>

<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="group1" value="2">
<label for="radio2">Option2</label>
```

Comment: thanks, i do need to have one "checked" by default and the `dynamicValidation` can change to true at any time (based on another input), so, unfortunately, making the whole element disabled is not ideal.

Comment: yeah, your best bet is to disable your radiobuttongroup because using your click, you're going to have to click for it to execute and it's not ideal in this situation since it doesn't seem to be supported in IE.

Comment: I made some changes to the example if you wanna take a look.

Comment: i do understand your point, but you are suggesting plainly to make the controls disabled which is not applicable since there is a dynamic validation that defines whether the selected option can be changed or not, making a control disabled leaves little or no room for such validation.

Comment: I'm sure there's better ways and you can make the validation to fit your needs.  For example, if `dynamicValidation = false` then disable the radiosbuttons, if not then don't.